If I have Schengen Long Term residence permit, can I enter the Schengen area from another Schengen country than the issuing country Czechia
I got residence permit (long term) of Czech Republic to start my PhD studies in a Czech University. I am from Asia. I am thinking of booking flight tickets from the capital of my country to Bratislava, Slovakia instead of Prague as my university is in Czech Republic but quite close to Bratislava.
A booking agent suggested me this. So, is it possible for me to enter Schengen Area from Bratislava instead of Prague even though the issuing country is Czechia? Will there be any issues? I am nervous as international travel is already very stressful!

Yes that's perfectly fine and one of the points of the Schengen area. With a residence permit from a neighboring country, this happens all the time and is completely unproblematic.

Will it be not a problem that I am going to Czechia for the 1st time?

If there’s something else suspicious about you, then going to the Schengen area for the first time might make them exercise extra caution. But entering the Schengen area through a different country is the least suspicious thing ever.

@user You got a residence permit from outside the country? Or a long-stay visa? A visit to a country on the other end of the Schengen area like Greece, Portugal or Estonia could raise questions if that's the first time you use a visa but a reasonable transit on your way to the Czech Republic is perfectly normal and expected.

@user why would it matter that it is the first time?
